# Robocopy behaves differently when running directly or from powershell script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a script that copies a file from a network location to a local folder using robocopy.

When I run following powershell 7 script from Visual Code, or execute the command directly in PS, only 1 file is copied as intended. If a run the script in powershell 4 files are copied. How can I copy the single file running from the script.

```
$dbname = "domoticz.db"
$sourcedir="\\ix2\PiBackup\domoticz\"
$targetdir="C:\tmp\DomoticzScripts\"
$dbfile = $targetdir + $dbname

robocopy $sourcedir $targetdir $db -njh
```

Output running it directly or VS Code debugger

```
          New Dir          1    \\ix2\PiBackup\domoticz\
100%        New File               8.9 m        domoticz.db

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :    8.96 m    8.96 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            70709894 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            4046.052 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : zaterdag 30 mei 2020 11:45:40
```

Running it in a script

```
          New Dir          4    \\ix2\PiBackup\domoticz\
100%        New File               8.9 m        domoticz.db
100%        New File               32768        domoticz.db-shm
100%        New File                   0        domoticz.db-wal
100%        New File               9.0 m        domoticz_.db

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         4         4         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   18.05 m   18.05 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            75125841 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            4298.735 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : zaterdag 30 mei 2020 11:47:06
```

Comment: Is `robocopy $sourcedir $targetdir $db -njh` a typo, because you have not defined `$db` in the posted code. It should be `robocopy $sourcedir $targetdir $dbname -njh`.

Comment: Correct. The variable was renamed and the old name still in memory

Comment: I have tested it with powershell v7.1 prevfiew 2 and cannot reproduce it when copying from "D:\test\tmp\source" to "D:\test\tmp\target" (I have also used the same filenames like in your example). So I think its a local Problem on your end. The only advises I can give you is maybe to use the powershell internal cmdlet copy-item or to dig deeper into the issue. Also give robocopy $sourcedir $targetdir $dbname '/njh' a try while your solution seems to work here perfectly fine.